# Is there a way to automatically call pander for each cell in an RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

When working in a RMarkdown file, I end up needing to call `%>% pander` after each statement I want to show in order to get the results to be displayed in the nice format that pander creates.

Is there any way to get RMarkdown / knitr to automatically send all of the results to pander in order to determine how it should print them?

````
```{r}
# default output looks bad
USJudgeRatings
```

```{r}
library(magrittr)
library(pander)

# With pander it looks much nicer
panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
USJudgeRatings %>% pander
```
````

[image]
[image]

Comment: That was the original goal of the `pander` package, to automatically transform R objects into markdown :) See eg the [Brew to Pandoc](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) section in the documentation, which describes a literate programming framework similar to `knitr` to achieve this goal. But this is also possible with `knitr` and `rmarkdown`, I think you need to tweak the hooks described at http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/